# CakePHP 2.0 i18n relations

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization

Anybody know about i18n relation in CakePHP 2.0? Are there materials about this?

Comment: Or which php framework supports i18n witch relations models?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation on the subject.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html

Comment: I recommend this tutorial, I tried it and got my translations working.